# How to execute multiple queries using psql command from bash shell?

Tags: database, postgresql, shell

I need to execute postgresql queries from command line using psql -c command.
For every psql command, it opens a new tcp connection to connect to the database server and execute query which is a overhead for large number of queries.

Currently I can execute single query like this:

```
psql -U postgres -h <ip_addr> -c "SELECT * FROM xyz_table;"
```

When I tried to execute multiple queries as below, but only the last query got executed.

```
psql -U postgres -h <ip_addr> -c "SELECT * FROM xyz_table; SELECT * FROM abc_table;"
```

Can anyone help me and tell me the proper way to do it?

Comment: Both statements are executed but only the last one returns as a result set. Check the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks, @FrankHeikens!  I think you should also add that as an answer (or propose an edit to the accepted answer).  The top answer promotes the misinformation that only one command gets processed.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`-c` processes only one command. Without it however `psql` expects commands to be passed into standard input, e.g.:

```
psql -U postgres -h <ip_addr> <database_name> << EOF
SELECT * FROM xyz_table;
SELECT * FROM abc_table;
EOF
```

Or by using `echo` and pipes.

Comment: I also read about `psql -U postgres -h <ip_addr> <database_name> -f -` to do the same. Any pros or cons?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík should be exactly the same.

Comment: As Wildcard noted in the question comment, executing with -c <command> will actually execute all the statements, but only the result of last one will be returned.

Comment: Yes that nice but if i really need to execute psql two times, and keep the commands at the same session, is that possible?

Comment: Current version of psql allows to use multiple `-c` commands.

Answer (score 28):

Specify each command with consecutive `-c` flags:

```
psql -c "select now()" -c "select version()" -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1
```

The output of the above command:

```
              now              
-------------------------------
 2017-12-26 20:25:45.874935+01
(1 row)

                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 24):

Using `echo` and a pipe to fit it on a single line:

```
echo 'SELECT * FROM xyz_table; \n SELECT * FROM abc_table' | psql -U postgres
```

Comment: On some systems you may need to do `echo -e ...`

Comment: @cbrown On those systems (too), you should almost certainly prefer `printf` over `echo -e`

Answer (score 19):

The `--file` parameter executes a file's content

```
psql -U postgres -h <ip_addr> -f "my_file.psql"
```

All the output will be sent to standard output

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: This is best Option!

Answer (score 0):

The "clean" solution is to pass multiple `-c` options:

```
$ psql ... -c 'select 1 as a' -c "select 'foo' as b"
 a
---
 1
(1 row)

  b
-----
 foo
(1 row)
```

Notable benefit: you can use backslash commands this way, e.g. `\x`.

(@leo-y points this out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803651/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-using-psql-command-from-bash-shell#comment114293740_28803698))