# postgresql: run SQL commands using psql in commandline

Tags: postgresql

I have the below three lines to be run in commandline using psql how can i do it.

```
CREATE DATABASE myproject;
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
```

I just want to pass the sql strings as it is.

Comment: Put them into a file, then use `psql ... -f script.sql`

Comment: I am writing a script i want them to be visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute multiple queries using psql command from bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803651/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-using-psql-command-from-bash-shell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) `psql -c 'command;'`

```
psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE myproject;' -c "CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';" -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;'
```

Answer (score 3):

As @horse suggested `-f filename` is a better option. You can  also put them into a variable using a here document and execute it with the `-c` option .

```
read -r -d '' my_sqls << EOM
CREATE DATABASE myproject;
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
EOM
psql -c "$my_sqls"   # running all  the lines.
```

Comment: The temporary variable is just a complication; Bash trivially allows you to pass a multi-line string basically anywhere you can put a string which doesn't contain newlines.